# How do I show drop-down while typing using Draftjs Modifier

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I want to give hint or auto suggestion while user typing , I got an array which have four suggestion and I also able to append to word selection,

how do I use Draftjs Modifier to to show list of option exact below the word as auto complete

or how do I create entity with drop-down , so that I can update the Editor state, and it will look like normal drop-down.